# MongoDB Java Async Driver replaceOne doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a document with MongoDB Async Java Driver and my code is below,

```
// jsonString is a string of "{_id=5715e426ed3522391f106e68, name=Alex}
final Document document = Document.parse(jsonString);

Document newDocument = document.append("status", "processing");
mongoDbCollection.replaceOne(document, newDocument, (updateResult, throwable) -> {
              if (updateResult != null) {
                 log.info("UPDATED DOC ::::::>>> " + newDocument.toJson());
                 log.info("UPDATED RESULT ::::>> "+updateResult.toString());
              } else {
                 throwable.printStackTrace();
                 log.error(throwable.getMessage());
              }
   });
```

As per the logging, I do see the updated document as below,

```
INFO: UPDATED DOC ::::::>>> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5715e426ed3522391f106e68" }, "status":"processing"}
INFO: UPDATED RESULT ::::>> AcknowledgedUpdateResult{matchedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upsertedId=null}
```

But when I see the collection via `Robmongo` I do not see the updated document and it still shows the old document. I have double checked I am looking in the same collection and there aren't any exceptions. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this line:

```
Document newDocument = document.append("status", "processing");
```

Where you "thought" you were just assigning a "new document copy", but actually this "also" modifies the `document` object to append the field.

As such, the query does not match, just as indicated in your output:

```
{matchedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upsertedId=null}
           // ^ Right here! See 0 matched
```

So what you want is a "clone". It's not straightforward with a `Document`, but can be done with this slightly "hacky" method:

```
Document document = Document.parse(jsonString);

Document newDocument = Document.parse(document.toJson()).append("status","processing");

System.out.println(newDocument);
System.out.println(document);
```

Now you will see that `newDocument` contains the addition, whilst `document` remains unaltered, which is not the case with your current code, and why the query does not match anything to update.